# How to wait for progress bar using Web Driver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Action:
if i click any link , progress bar was displayed once page loaded completely then that progress bar was hided

Doubts:
we want to automate the above action, how can i check the progress action complete or not

below are the html code

once i click the link html looks like this

```
<div id ="divProgress" class="progresswindow" style="display: block;"></div>
```

then page loading completed html looks like this

```
<div id ="divProgress" class="progresswindow" style="display: none;"></div>
```

so how can i check this progress bar completed or not, currently i'm using Thread.sleep(), but some time web driver raise the exception

```
Other element would receive the click: <div id="divProgress" class="progresswindow" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

Please provide an suggestion how this handle with Explicit wait

Answer (score 6):

Rather than `Thread.sleep()` to wait for any condition, you should be using the [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) classes.

In your case, you should wait until the div with the progress bar becomes invisible:

```
    long timeoutInSeconds = 30;
    new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds)
  .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("divProgress")));
```

As you've found, `Thread.sleep()` is too brittle to be used safely in test code - you should always be waiting for something you can check for. As a bonus your tests will probably execute a lot faster!

Comment: With thanks to @alb-i986 who suggested edits that improved the post greatly (I was not aware of the built-in ExpectedConditions) but the edits were down ranked. They definitely improved the post though!

Comment: you're welcome -- Thank *you* for accepting my suggestions :)